# Building a non decreasing function from any other function

Tags: calculus, special-functions

What can be said of this function? Does it have a name? Would it be possible to build an equation for it? Is it implemented in any mathematical software?
$$f_g(x)= \max \{g(y) \mid y\in [0,x]\}$$
I can clearly imagine it's graph, $f$ sticks to $g$ as long as it is greater than its local minimum "so far" whilst it basically "bridges over" $g$'s "valleys" when it goes below it.

If you are interested in why I am asking the question:
I was playing in Matlab and imagined such a function for visualising Taylor's formula with the Lagrange remainder, by determining the worst possible $c$ and graphing a region in which the approximated function actually lies (by $c$ I mean the value from the following formula).
$$ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!} (x-x_0)^{k+1} $$
This however shouldn't matter as I find $f_g(x)$ interesting on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called the *running maximum* of $g$. It is studied for stochastic processes in particular in financial mathematics. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Running_maximum.